# Do we need to change anything in main jquery library ever to use jquery noconflict?

Tags: jquery

Do we need to change anything in main jquery library ever to use jquery noconflict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to change the jquery lib itself but you have to change your code using jquery. Instead of **$('#myid')** you have to use **jQuery('#myid')** then.

For more information on the noconflict mode visit http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries

Comment: can i make blind find and replace $ to jQuery? is Q should be bigger?

Comment: When you don't use any Plugins it should work fine. You may just replace all of them and then run a short test. And yes jQuery is case sensitive. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Not in the jquery library itself, but some plugins rely on the $ variable.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear, is this what you mean?

```
 jQuery.noConflict();
 jQuery('#id'); //instead of $('#id');
```

Because then you should change all your code to use jQuery instead of $. If you mean your won extensions, you should set them up as follow:

```
(function($){
   $.myPlugin = function() { ]
})(jQuery);
```

Then you are safe for people who use jQuery.noConflict

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure it's a big NO. You don't really have to.